# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32 visual studio 2008

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Error points to  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

error occurs when i try to leave fields null except for the primary key field OEID

any syntax revision suggestion would be much appreciated

```
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = sqlconn.CreateCommand
        sqlconn.Open()

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "AddOfficeEquipmentProfile"


        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_SerialNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "sgh5960").Value = DBNull.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_PropertyNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "j7h7h6g6f2").Value = DBNull.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_MacAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "j7h7:h6g6f2").Value = DBNull.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Static_IP", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15, "192.168.1.5").Value = DBNull.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Vendor", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "ADWAYS").Value = DBNull.Value

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_PurchaseDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_WarrantyStatus", SqlDbType.Char, 2, "IN").Value = DBNull.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15, "Good").Value = DBNull.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Dept_Code", SqlDbType.Char, 3, "ADM").Value = DBNull.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Location_Code", SqlDbType.Char, 8, "ADM_OFC").Value = DBNull.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Remarks", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000, "ACTIVE").Value = DBNull.Value

        cmd.Parameters("@OE_SerialNo").Value = txtSerialNo.Text
        cmd.Parameters("@OE_PropertyNo").Value = txtPropertyNo.Text
        cmd.Parameters("@OE_MacAddress").Value = txtMacAddress.Text
        cmd.Parameters("@OE_Static_IP").Value = txtStaticIP.Text
        cmd.Parameters("@OE_Vendor").Value = txtVendor.Text
        cmd.Parameters("@OE_PurchaseDate").Value = dtpPurchaseDate.Value
        cmd.Parameters("@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear").Value = txtWarrantyInclusiveYear.Text
        cmd.Parameters("@OE_WarrantyStatus").Value = txtWarrantyStatus.Text
        cmd.Parameters("@OE_Status").Value = txtStatus.Text
        cmd.Parameters("@OE_Dept_Code").Value = cmbDeptCode.Text
        cmd.Parameters("@OE_Location_Code").Value = cmbLocationCode.Text
        cmd.Parameters("@OE_Remarks").Value = txtRemarks.Text
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlconn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between Null and "".

"" is an empty string and you are assigning an empty string to an numeric column, probably WarrantyInclusiveYear

You need to check if the column is empty before making the assignment, thus...

```
If txtWarrantyInclusiveYear.Text.Trim <> "" Then
   cmd.Parameters("@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear").Value = txtWarrantyInclusiveYear.Text
End If
```

but this is not very good code, what you should do is...

```
Dim nValue As Integer = 0

If Integer.TryParse(txtWarrantyInclusiveYear.Text,nValue) Then
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear").Value = nValue
End If
```

Comment: even if serialNo and propertyNo is a varchar field?

Comment: should i put if on all integer and varchar fields? except for the char?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake it's WarrantyInclusiveYear that's the Integer column, not SerialNo or PropertyNo. BTW: Unless you have a real need for Nulls in numeric columns (E.g. to calculate averages or something similar) then I'd avoid it. Set them to a default value or zero to avoid all sorts of nasty complications later on. There are perfectly valid reasons for Nulls in numeric columns but do it by design rather than as something left incomplete or as an oversight.